# gnuplot: plot disappears when adding "set xrange"

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I've got a strange problem using "set xrange" with a simple code and I don't get it.
I have the code:

```
set style data histograms    
set style histogram clustered gap 1    
set style fill solid 1.0     
set boxwidth 0.9    
set auto x    
set xtic rotate by -70 scale 1     
set yrange [0:32]    
set ylabel 'percentage [%]'    
set xlabel 'Year'    
set key top left

plot '../ölkj.txt' using 3 title 'ölkj', 'asdf.txt' u 2 title 'asdf'
```

Everything is fine. But when I add

```
set xrange[1997:2014]
```

the plot disappears, just the axes, their label and the legend remains.

The data is in the following format:

```
2012    14,81   20
2013    15,11   18,18
2014    15,83   20
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem most definitely is the way you are plotting and trying to set xrange on time data vs how the timestamps are. Please post a snippet from your data file.

Comment: Hey Zahaib, thanx for your effort. These are some data...

Comment: Which file is that data from? can you edit your question to add enough data from both to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem just now using time data:

I used

```
set timefmt "%s"
set ydata time
set yrange [0:600]
```

and my plot disappeared.

Replacing `set yrange [0:600]` with `set yrange ["0":"600"]` made it appear again.

This might be caused by gnuplot not parsing the yrange arguments when its not enclosed in `"` and using a different internal representation for timestamps.

I could observe this by looking at the mouse-coordinates on the empty plot. Pressing "Apply autoscale" made gnuplot show my plot. The mouse-coordinates then looked totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve by `set xrange` is to get the year labels on your x-axis. You can do that by just altering your plot command to:

```
plot '../ölkj.txt' using 3:xtic(1) title 'ölkj', 'asdf.txt' u 2:xtic(1) title 'asdf'
```

Comment: no, I want to limit the x-range. for example with this three data sets "set xrange[2013:2014]". If I add the xtics there is no data point left on the x-axis. And neither the plot.

Comment: @user3837801 Gnuplot doesn't really expect x-cordinates when plotting histograms. It will itself set integers on the x-axis to evenly space the clusters. If you want to adjust x-axis then just use integers in set xrange. Try this  `set xrange [0:4]` and play around with these numbers.